# how to assign values to global variables in a function and use them in other functions in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I tried to declare variable in dart in this way but it shows a warning due to null safety.

```
double latitude; 
double longitude;
```

Again I tried like this but the values  did not assign to the variables latitude and longitude in the function varcheck().

```
double? latitude;
double? longitude;
void varcheck(){
  latitude=33;
  longitude=44;
}
void main() {
  print(latitude);
  print(longitude);
}
```

**Output**
null
null

how to assign the values to the global variables in a function and use them in any other functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code hope its help to you. just call your `varcheck()` inside main main method

```
double? latitude;
double? longitude;
void varcheck() {
  latitude = 33;
  longitude = 44;
}

void main() {
  varcheck();
  print(latitude);
  print(longitude);
}
```

Your result->
33
44

Answer (score 2):

You did not call **varcheck()** function .So you have to call this function first.

```
double? latitude;
double? longitude;
void varcheck(){
  latitude=33;
  longitude=44;
}
void main() {
  varcheck();
  print(latitude);
  print(longitude);
}
```